# Chromebook: how do you enable Linux apps?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, debian, google-chrome-os

I saw that Chromebooks are starting to get support for running Linux apps. I read that the first supported Chromebook was the Google Pixelbook.

**For machines that support Linux apps, how do you enable Linux apps?**

Unfortunately I do not have a Google Pixelbook. I have a Dell Chromebook 13 inch.

**How can I tell if my machine, Dell Chromebook 13, supports Linux apps?**

Answer (score 2):

[Linux apps support requires hardware virtualization (VT-x)](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/containers_and_vms.md#Hardware-Requirements) to work. Therefore to check if your Chromebook may get Linux app support or not, verify your CPU to see if it has VT-x.

Dell Chromebook 13 uses [Core™ i5-5200U](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3024380/hardware/dell-chromebook-13-review-carbon-fiber-and-extra-long-battery-life-make-it-a-class-act.html) which [does have VT-x support](https://ark.intel.com/products/85212/Intel-Core-i5-5200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz), so chances are you'll be able to run Linux apps in the future

You can also [check the list in xda](https://www.xda-developers.com/chromebooks-linux-app-support/) if your Chromebook is one of the *Confirmed Chromebooks with Linux App Support* or *Upcoming devices with support, not yet verified by XDA*, or isn't listed in the non-supported table

---

Right now the feature is still in beta, so if your Chromebook supports Linux apps you'll need to enable it with the following steps

- Go to chrome://components/ and check for an update for `cros-termina`
- Go to chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-crostini-ui and enable the flag
- Restart Chromebook
- Open Settings menu and in the `Linux (beta)` page click `Turn on`

https://9to5google.com/2018/06/03/how-to-enable-linux-apps-beta-chrome-os-android-basics/

Hopefully it'll be released [in December](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/05/09/linux_chrome_os/)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it looks like your Dell Chromebook 13, along with all other Kernel 3.14 systems, will not be receiving Linux apps after all. In August 2018, Google [announced their intention to drop support for them due to security concerns](https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/comments/99gpkw/chromebooks_with_314_kernel_will_not_get_linux/).

As for other systems, all you need to do to see if your device supports Linux apps is to go into the Settings and look for Linux on the left pane, like this:

[image: Linux in settings menu on Chrome OS]

Comment: i updated my chromebook and didn't see it... so i don't have it yet. my chromebook is a Dell Chromebook 13. It MIGHT get linux apps because it came out at the same time as the original Google-Pixelbook and has Linux Kernel 3.14 (when i do uname -a). And I have an Intel 3205u which according to Intel Ark has virtualization technology.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Unfortunately it looks like your Chromebook 13 will not get Linux apps at all, see my updated answer. Please tell me if I have thoroughly answered your question.